# Animate SVG dotted line a different color progressively

Tags: animation, svg

I have this SVG

```html
<svg width="455" height="102" viewBox="0 0 455 102" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M451.556 25.1576C435.152 73.3258 366.885 125.586 296.309 84.449C257.221 59.9286 203.507 18.9945 182.449 13.1117C114.633 -12.4168 41.0939 12.8604 2.57437 66.1813" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="10 20 10 20 10 20"/>
<path d="M451.556 25.1576C435.152 73.3258 366.885 125.586 296.309 84.449C257.221 59.9286 203.507 18.9945 182.449 13.1117C114.633 -12.4168 41.0939 12.8604 2.57437 66.1813" stroke="#222222" stroke-opacity="0.3" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="10 20 10 20 10 20"/>
</svg>
```

My goal is to animate each square a blue color based on some application state , the idea is that it is a loader and it finishes all blue once the data has came in. So the end result will look like this

```html
<svg width="455" height="102" viewBox="0 0 455 102" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M451.556 25.1576C435.152 73.3258 366.885 125.586 296.309 84.449C257.221 59.9286 203.507 18.9945 182.449 13.1117C114.633 -12.4168 41.0939 12.8604 2.57437 66.1813" stroke="#007CFF" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="10 20 10 20 10 20"/>
</svg>
```

Appreciate any tips and how to go about doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use an SVG mask animation.**

- The bottom layer is a blue curve
- Top layer - gray curve

When the mask is animated from left to right, the upper gray curve is cut through and the lower blue curve becomes visible as a result.

```
 <animate attributename="x" begin="svg1.click" dur="4s" values="-452;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

An illusion is created of filling the curve gray color with a blue.

*Animation will start after clicking*

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="455" height="102" viewBox="0 0 455 102" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <mask id="msk">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <rect fill="black" x="-452" y="0" width="450" height="100" >
      <animate id="an" attributeName="x" begin="svg1.click;an.end+0.5s" dur="7s" values="-452;10" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>
  </mask>
</defs>

<path id="path" d="M451.556 25.1576C435.152 73.3258 366.885 125.586 296.309 84.449C257.221 59.9286 203.507 18.9945 182.449 13.1117C114.633 -12.4168 41.0939 12.8604 2.57437 66.1813" stroke="#007CFF" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="10 20"/> 

<path  mask="url(#msk)" d="M451.556 25.1576C435.152 73.3258 366.885 125.586 296.309 84.449C257.221 59.9286 203.507 18.9945 182.449 13.1117C114.633 -12.4168 41.0939 12.8604 2.57437 66.1813" stroke="#BCBCBC" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="10 20"/> 
</svg>
```

### Update

as commented @Dmitriy

> For Example- the data comes in in 4 seconds instead of 7 seconds -
> could i instantly finish the animation once that happens?

For this you can use [repeatDur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/repeatDur) This attribute stops the animation from playing after a certain amount of time from the start of the animation! Simply put, repeatDur limits the duration of an animation.

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="455" height="102" viewBox="0 0 455 102" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid">
<defs>
  <mask id="msk">
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <rect fill="black" x="-452" y="0" width="450" height="100" >
      <animate id="an" attributeName="x" begin="svg1.click" dur="7s" repeatDur="4s" values="-452;10" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>
  </mask>
</defs>

<path id="path" d="M451.556 25.1576C435.152 73.3258 366.885 125.586 296.309 84.449C257.221 59.9286 203.507 18.9945 182.449 13.1117C114.633 -12.4168 41.0939 12.8604 2.57437 66.1813" stroke="#007CFF" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="10 20"/> 

<path  mask="url(#msk)" d="M451.556 25.1576C435.152 73.3258 366.885 125.586 296.309 84.449C257.221 59.9286 203.507 18.9945 182.449 13.1117C114.633 -12.4168 41.0939 12.8604 2.57437 66.1813" stroke="#BCBCBC" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="10 20"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this its working great, would you know of a way I can finish the animation dynamically? For Example- the data comes in in 4 seconds instead of 7 seconds - could i instantly finish the animation once that happens?

Comment: @Dmitriy For this you can use repeatDur This attribute stops the animation from playing after a certain amount of time from the start of the animation! Simply put, repeatDur limits the duration of an animation.

Comment: Thanks again @Alexandr_TT , this stops it after 4 seconds - but it doesn't render the rest of the line blue - is there a way to do that within this animation? 
So - it stops at 4 seconds - And it quickly animates the rest of the line the blue color

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Dmitriy Thank you for your question too. Only js solution can help in this situation. Need to calculate the data transfer time and substitute it dynamically in the **dur** attribute Ask a new question with the JS tag